# Can I draw a multiplot when one subplot is plt and the other sns?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to visualise linear regression plot and residual plot one next to another - Is this even possible? I know how to draw them separately but can anybody help me to draw them on the same canvas? Here is my attempt but first graph is drawn, while second one is left empty. I get error message: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'sns'

```
fig1, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 3))

ax[0].scatter(X_train, y_train, color = 'red')
ax[0].plot(X_train, lm1.predict(X_train), color = 'blue')
ax[0].set_title('Simple Linear Regression')
ax[0].set_xlabel('highway-mpg')
ax[0].set_ylabel('price')


ax[1].sns.residplot(df['highway-mpg'], df['price'])
ax[1].set_title('Residual plot')
ax[1].set_xlabel('highway-mpg')
ax[1].set_ylabel('price')

fig1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should it be:

```
fig1, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 3))

ax[0].scatter(X_train, y_train, color = 'red')
ax[0].plot(X_train, lm1.predict(X_train), color = 'blue')
ax[0].set_title('Simple Linear Regression')
ax[0].set_xlabel('highway-mpg')
ax[0].set_ylabel('price')

### change is here
sns.residplot(df['highway-mpg'], df['price'], ax=ax[1])
ax[1].set_title('Residual plot')
ax[1].set_xlabel('highway-mpg')
ax[1].set_ylabel('price')
```